# Servicing a Voigtlander Bessa from 1929 - how to open the lens assembly?

Tags: lens, repair, old-lenses, old-cameras

I recently acquired a Voigtlander Bessa from 1929. It works but there's a dead insect into the lens assembly (between the glasses) and some fungus/dust. I'm trying to open it to remove the insect and clean the lenses, so I removed the lens assembly from the camera and started removing all the screws and everything that could possibly be removed. Now I'm stuck: there's apparently nothing left to remove, but the thing won't open. Any idea on how to proceed?
I'm attaching a couple of pictures of the lens assembly as it is now (sorry for the watermark...).

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Thanks

Comment: That actually worked! It was just very very hard to unscrew, I was scared of damaging it. How can I mark your comment as a solution?

Comment: It has to be an answer before it can be marked as such?

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I've moved my comment into the answer field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the front and back lens assemblies (what you have is often referred to as lens in shutter) unscrew from the shutter/aperture body. Have you tried unscrewing the lens barrel from the shutter rather than taking the shutter apart? Can you see threads on the outside of the lens barrel (either front or back)?

Comment: that was very useful. I was able to unscrew the back element from the shutter with a pair of pliers, no problem whatsoever. I wasn't able to unscrew the middle element, though, but I managed to clean it with the shutter open.